# print multidimensional array with foreach loop 3

Tags: php

`msgs` is a 2 dimension array

Is it possible to do:

```
foreach ($msgs['error'] as $msg)
```

?

I want to print only the value in "error":

```
 msgs['error']['first value']

 msgs['error']['second value']

 msgs['error']['third value']
```

etc...

Comment: No, but it's possible to do `foreach($msgs['error'] ... )`. Why are you asking here when you could have discovered it for yourself in seconds?

Comment: I google it, but haven't found. BTW - I tried: foreach($msgs['error'] .  not working...

Comment: "Discovered it yourself" does not even mean googling -- you can type in the code and see if the compiler accepts it! Anyway, as you see there are now more people giving you the same answer. If the answer is still "wrong", then it should be pretty clear that's because the *question* is bad. For example, you don't show us what the array looks like.

Comment: here:


Array ( [required] => Array ( [סוג משתמש] => שדה 'סוג משתמש' לא יכול להיות ריק [שם פרטי] => שדה 'שם פרטי' לא יכול להיות ריק [מייל] => שדה 'מייל' לא יכול להיות ריק [סיסמא] => שדה 'סיסמא' לא יכול להיות ריק [אימות סיסמא] => שדה 'אימות סיסמא' לא יכול להיות ריק [שאלת אימות] => שדה 'שאלת אימות' לא יכול להיות ריק ) [error] => שא כל שדות החובה מלאים. נא לבדוק שהשדות המסומנים בכוכבית מלאים )

Comment: One last comment and that's enough for me: it is obvious from the output you posted that `$msgs['error']` is a **string**, not an array. So how would it ever be possible to `foreach` over it?

Answer (score 1):

Just like this:

```
foreach ($msgs as $msg_outer)
    print_r($msg_outer);
```

PHP will loop through the outer values. If you want to access the inner values, just add another foreach in the foreach:

```
foreach ($msgs as $msg_outer)
    foreach ($msg_outer as $msg_inner)
        print_r($msg_inner);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($msgs['error'] as $msg)  
{
    print $msg;
}
```

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Are you sure `$msgs` is populated?

Answer (score 0):

Check the array keys if you're having trouble accessing them with foreach();

```
print_r(array_keys($msgs));
```

Then work forwards from there.

Src: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php